# SAS DATA Step, Why is this simple IF statement not working?

Tags: sas

im not getting it, 
I have this if statement  determine which value to store en tmp variable

```
%let csvfil= L:\work\sij\ss.csv;
filename ss "L:\work\sij\ss.txt";
data tester;


if a = 1 then
    tmp = "infile '" || strip("&csvfil") || "'";
else if a = 2 then
    tmp = "infile '" || strip("&csvfil") || "'" || "encoding='windows'";
put tmp;

run;
```

So When a = 1 it 
should put "infile '" || strip("&csvfil") || "'"; in tmp variable 
When a is not 1 it should put 
 tmp = "infile '" || strip("&csvfil") || "'" || "encoding='windows'";

It doesn't happen ?

Then i tried a simple test 
this works ok so really i dont get it.

```
data simse;
 a=2;
 if a = 1 then 
  tmp = 'simse';
 else
  tmp = 'frede';
 run;
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  It looks like you are trying to build a INFILE statement as the value of a character variable. What are you going to do with once you have made that character variable?

Comment: Seconding they why? Especially when SAS has the `filevar` option or `filename` statement that let you change the file name settings or build the filevar dynamically. FYI - there's also a filename function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DATA Step does not contain a `SET` statement, so the data step compiler does not know abouit a variable named `a` at the `if` statement.  The compiler will 'add' the variable `a` to the PDV as uninitialized (which means it's value will be the missing value `.`).

Your log should show

```
NOTE: Variable a is uninitialized.
```

Since a missing value does not match the `if` or the `else if` clause the `tmp` variable is never assigned a value.

The compiler does not know about a `tmp` variable at the point of it's first assignment, so the compiler 'adds' `tmp` to the PDV with a type and length derived from the type and length of the first expression it is assigned from.

```
data tester;


if a = 1 then
    tmp = "infile '" || strip("&csvfil") || "'";
else if a = 2 then
    tmp = "infile '" || strip("&csvfil") || "'" || "encoding='windows'";
put tmp;

run;
```